# Error After Installing CodeBuilder (Beta)

Tags: code-builder

**Compilation Failure**

> /CodeBuilder/appInsightsService/appInsightsService.js:57,4 : LWC1001:
> Unexpected compilation error: Unexpected token [Compilation Failure
> /CodeBuilder/appInsightsService/appInsightsService.js:57,4 : LWC1001:
> Unexpected compilation error: Unexpected token]

**Additional exception on component load: Compilation Failure**

> /CodeBuilder/appInsightsService/appInsightsService.js:57,4 : LWC1001:
> Unexpected compilation error: Unexpected token. Caused by: Compilation
> Failure   /CodeBuilder/appInsightsService/appInsightsService.js:57,4 :
> LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: Unexpected token [Compilation
> Failure   /CodeBuilder/appInsightsService/appInsightsService.js:57,4 :
> LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: Unexpected token]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: What kind of org? How did you try to install the package? Etc.

Comment: Will probably make more sense to report it here -- https://github.com/forcedotcom/try-code-builder-feedback/issues

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This issue is now fixed!

There is an open issue for this on the Code Builder feedback [repository](https://github.com/forcedotcom/try-code-builder-feedback/issues/148).

This is a  known [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/try-code-builder-feedback/issues/148) and we hope to hear back from the Product soon!